# Write a query which add two fields of a document and compare their sum to third field in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have one document, say:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("538b7128cf16e3ea5a1ab23c"),   
        "pgDownloadTime" : NumberLong(9776),
        "pgAccessTime" : NumberLong("1401647400058"),
        "expiredTime" : NumberLong("1401647468678"),
        "contentType" : 1,
        "articleId" : "35909002",
}
```

My query will be:

```
db.pageTrendLog.findOne({"expiredTime" : {$lte : "pgDownloadTime"+"pgAccessTime"}});
```

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one part of the answer; adding two fields together. Still trying to figure out how to compare the total of pgDownloadTime +pgAccessTime with expiredTime

// Add pgDownloadTime and pgAccessTime

```
db.pageTrendLog.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id" : ObjectId("538c304b7446cf13431a2c5c") } }, 
      { $project : 
        {  
          'pgDownloadTime' : '$pgDownloadTime',  
          'pgAccessTime' : '$pgAccessTime', 
          'total' : {'$add' : [ '$pgDownloadTime', '$pgAccessTime' ]}
        }
      }]);
```

Comment: HI @Craig Efrein Thanks for the response but it is a aggregation which will give this addition in result set. I was looking for some query where in can use in in single hit

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get to what you want with the aggregation framework, which Craig is already working on, and that is your only option until these feature requests (and maybe some others) are implemented (i.e. you cannot do this with a simple query at present):

- [Compare Document Fields in Queries (SERVER-2702)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2702)
- [Expression Native Support (SERVER-2549)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2549)
- [comparison operation right hand side should be expressions (SERVER-7623)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7623)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query which worked for me. 
This query says - Find documents from the collection in which expired time is less than or equal to the sum of page download time and page access time.

Should you face a problem, let me know -

```
db.pageTrendLog.findOne({$expr: { $lte: [ {$sum :["$pgDownloadTime","$pgAccessTime"]}, "$expiredTime"] }});
```